# Real analysis- Bernoulli's inequality

Tags: analysis

If $0 < c < 1$ show that $c_n → 0$; and if $c > 0$, show that $c^{1/n} → 1$

[Hint: Use Bernoulli 's inequality for each, once with $c = 1/(1 + x)$, $x > 0$ and once with $c^{1/n} = 1+ x_n$, where $x_n > 0$.]

Comment: Ok, you have some hints. What have you done so far?

Comment: So far i have tried but nothing

Comment: If you have tried, what is it, and if you haven't tried anything, why won't you?

Comment: The question is not much clear at the moment, try to improve it and show your work here. If you are just interested to the answer you can find many duplicates here on MSE. Otherwise if you want find the solution by yourself by some hint revise your question.

Comment: Your question is unintelligible.

Comment: I don't even know what the question is. I don't know what you want to prove because the final arrow is pointing into empty space.

Comment: Sorry but i have forgotten something to write on exercise

Comment: To all: please consider that Georgee is a new contributor, try to follow the "Be Nice" policy and "Take care in asking for clarification, commenting".

Comment: Take a look here [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to edit the OP properly.

Comment: If 0<c<1 show that cn→0; and if c>0, show that c1/n→ 1

[Hint: Use Bernoulli 's inequality for each, once with c=1/(1+x), x>0 and once with c1/n=1+xn, where xn>0.]

Comment: Maybe you mean $c^n\to 0$ and $c^\frac1n\to 1$, revise your OP adding that and show what you have tried.

Comment: Are you interested to find the solution by yourself and learn something about that or you are just looking for a solution to an homework problem?

Comment: its a homework problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: with $x>0$ such that $c = 1/(1 + x)$ we get

$c^n=1/(1 + x)^n \le 1/(1 + nx) \le 1/(nx)$.